# How to make an iOS AVPlayer recover from a network stall?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I disconnect my device from the Internet while playing a video on an AVPlayer, it stalls after a few seconds but doesn't recover when I reconnect the Internet link.
How can I make it recover from that state?

I can detect when it runs out of playback buffer and stalls but the problem is to resume the playback when the Internet link is reconnected.

Comment: I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059019/avplayer-cannot-resume-upon-wifi-drops-in-ios-8