# AVPlayer cannot resume upon Wifi drops in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, wifi, avplayer, playback, duration

I'm using AVPlayer to play streaming video. When Wifi drops and later enables, I see that AVPlayer cannot resume, no matter how many times I call `AVPlayer play`, and its `currentItem` 's `duration` is NaN, `seekableTimeRanges` is empty.

This is not the case for iOS 7, it resumes and plays well. The workaround I can think of is to restart the player.

How to deal with this?

Comment: What are the delegates that you are handling for AVPlayer? How are you monitoring Wifi?

Comment: I emailed Apple and they accept it as a bug

Comment: Possible duplicate,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556521/avplayer-connection-loss-restarting

Comment: Same problem, if any one got solution then please share it here..