# ios - Background execution after connection loss

Tags: ios, stream, avplayer

My app streams radio. 
Everything works fine, expect when I have a connection drop.

When the app is in background and I lose the connection, the radio won't start again, until the app goes back in foreground.

I have a background thread called every 20 seconds, with a simple log (and other stuff of course) inside.
The log is displayed correctly every 20 seconds while app is in background.

However, if I lose the connection, the logs stop displaying, so I suppose something "pause" the app when nothing is doing in background, but I can't find where.

For the "connection loss", I activate the Network Link Conditioner (100% Loss) on the iPhone. 
I don't have troubles with a simulator.

I saw a similar post for this ([AVPlayer cannot resume upon Wifi drops in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059019/avplayer-cannot-resume-upon-wifi-drops-in-ios-8)), but it's not recent, and it's maybe resolved by Apple.

Thanks,